# When to save model state?

Tags: android

There are several activities in my my application. All of them use `MySingleton` to read and store some data.

- State of the singleton is loaded from file at first access.
- The state is frequently changes.
- The state is no so small (~1MB).
- This singleton is something like a model for my application.

So, I want to store it to the file only when no more changes will occure -- after stopping all activities. How can I do it?

Comment: You shouldn't do it "after stopping all activities" since you have no control over that.  You should do it in `onPause()` in every activity since you have no idea if your app will be killed when it goes to the background.  There was a similar discussion a few hours ago.  Just code according to the activity life cycle and don't make assumptions and everything will be cool.

Comment: @Simon ok, but what about 20 MB size? Android guide advices to avoid performing heavy operations during onPause() and use onStop() for it. On the other hand, as you said, there is no garanties onStop() will be called.

Comment: Correct, `onStop()` can't be used.  But, what on earth are you saving as "state" that takes 20MB?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, due to potential app crashes/low memory/battery pulled situations, storing discrete state changes as they're made will provide the best user experience.

That said and assuming you're in a situation that warrants not doing the above: you could register each Activity as it resumes with a Service that is sticky, unregister an Activity when it pauses, save state if there's no more registered Activities, finally stop the Service. You could also use binding to facilitate that behaviour (e.g. bind to Service, save state when last binding is unbound).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of Android and its process and memory management, you cannot ever 100% guarantee that your activities and applications will go through certain checkpoints in which you could safely store your state.

The best approach in my opinion would be to store the changes to the state as they happen. Does your entire state change every time? Probably just a part of it. Create a database and store only what changes every time it changes - that will be your safest bet.